Record, save and play back keyboard macros in VS Code
Trying to transition from NP++ to VS Code, I just seem to like the look of the latter :-) One of the features I like and use the most is keyboard macros- I use them for reformatting strings and so on. I came to realise that VS Code doesn't support this out of the box. I came across one extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tshino.kb-macro but I can't figure out how to save a macro and assign it to a keyboard shortcut- I have asked that developer on github.
In the meantime I was wondering if anything else exists out there. Even if I can't assign a keyboard shortcut, I am OK if there is a menu option for macros and a dropdown of the macros I have created that I can choose from.

Have you seen the How to customize shortcut keys for recording and playback  and How to save the recorded sequence for future use in the link you posted?

Thank you, I was able to find the needed information in the readme.md. My mistake for not having read it properly.

@ChuckLeviton you can write up an answer post. see [answer] and if necessary, /help/referencing
